# llamar una funcion php cuanndo la necesite

Tags: php

buen día, debo realizar unas comprobaciones para que imprima "hello world" en caso de que b=1 o b=2 se que eso se puede hacer en un if con el operador or pero el profesor quiere que la función que imprime el "hello world" sea llamada en el if de b=1 o en el otro if de b=2

la pregunta es como llamarla ahi dentro de los if, que sintaxis debe seguir?

gracias!

Comment: tienes código de muestra, o por lo menos pseudocodigo? ya que tu pregunta es muy confusa :/

Comment: que quieres hacer quéee???

Answer (score 1):

La pregunta no es muy clara, recomendaría que para una futura ocasión por lo menos ponga algún pseudo-código, si traduzco literalmente lo que está pidiendo sería algo así:

```
<?php

function sayHelloWord($number) {
    echo "Hello Word ($number) \n";
}

# Genera un número entre 0 y 5
$b = rand(0, 5);

if ($b == 1) {
    sayHelloWord($b);
} elseif ($b == 2) {
    sayHelloWord($b);
} else {
    echo "El numero es: " . $b ."\n";
}
```

La manera que creo que a la mayoría se le podría ocurrir sería:

```
<?
...
$values = [1,2];

if (in_array($b, $values)) {
    sayHelloWord($b);
} else {
    echo "El numero es: " . $b ."\n";
}
...
```

Si la respuesta no va por acá, entonces sería "sano" que publiques lo que has hecho y solicites la ayuda específicamente en el segmento del código que no ve bien.

Comment: Lo que yo he entendido y pensado es también la primera forma, sí :)

Answer (score 0):

Hasta donde entiendo, debes hacer las dos comparaciones, entonces podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$b = 0; //Le estableces el valor que desees
if ($b == 1){
    echo "Hello World";
}elseif($b == 2){
    echo "Hello World";
}else{
    //Hacer otra cosa
}
```